# SQL_Question asked in Interview

Tags: sql, oracle

This was the question asked to me in interview :

Input:

```
SQL> select col1,col2 from Hakuna_matata;

COL1                      ~             COL2
--------------------------------------------------~
A                         ~             2
B                         ~             1
C                         ~             3
```

I want output as

```
COL1                      ~             COL2
--------------------------------------------------~---
A                         ~             1
B                         ~             2
C                         ~             3
```

How you will do in SQL?

Please help me with the queries/way how this can be done .

Comment: what is you data in table?

Comment: So, how did the interview go?

Comment: There is no right answer for this problem because it's not a realistic business scenario. To be generous to the interviewer this seems like a test of how much Oracle SQL you know and how well you reason about problems. You're re-asking the question on StackOverflow, so hmmm .... Anyway, there are many different ways of solving the SQL puzzle hence this question is not a good fit for the site. Voting to close.

Comment: The correct answer is that you should ask the interviewer: what rule is used to generate such a result ? Before you start programming, you must gather the requirements and clarify the ambiguities. I guess you did not ask. If I were a recruiter, I would give you 0 points for this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can order by ascending both column in separate and then merge it using [with clauses](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause), `rownum` **EDIT** using @Kaushik Nayak  Tip in comments

```
with a as 
(select rownum as r,a1.* from (select col1, col3 from Hakuna_matata order by col1 asc ) a1)
, b as 
(select rownum as r,a2.* from (select col2  from Hakuna_matata order by col2 asc ) a2)
select a.col1, b.col2, a.col3 from a ,b where a.r=b.r;
```

col3 is example of adding more columns to select

Comment: SQL> with a as (select col1,rownum as r from Hakuna_matata order by col1 asc ) , b as (select col2,rownum as r from Hakuna_matata order by col2 asc ) select a.col1, b.col2 from a,b where a.r=b.r  ;

COL1        ~        COL2
--------------------------------------------------~------------------------------
B        ~    1
A        ~    2
C        ~    3

Comment: @Arun and user7294900, this solution will work if `ROWNUM` is used outside the nested `ORDER BY` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4f78/5

Comment: Go ahead..you don't need my permission...:-)

Answer (score 1):

As there is no explanation given on how `col2` should be generated (e.g. swapping the values or just re-numbering them), I'd go for:

```
select col1,   
       row_number() over (order by col1) as col2 
from Hakuna_matata;
```

Which produces the desired output - but it's unclear if that is the desired *solution*.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate to use `ascii` function in your case :

```
SQL> select col1, ( ascii(col1) - 64 ) col2 from Hakuna_matata;
```

Comment: This method's good and works for this particular example question, but will not work for general cases.  Otherwise I would up vote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way, but I think that you have to update table data:

```
update Hakuna_matata set col2=1 where col1='A';
update Hakuna_matata set col2=2 where col1='B';
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  All the other answers seem so complicated.  I would do:

```
select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
from Hakuna_matata
order by col1;
```

But the interviewer probably wants you to ask questions about what the ordering means, not simply come up with a solution that makes assumptions.

Comment: This is not going to work. `rownum` is assigned _before_ `order by` is evaluated. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0446d6e59840bdeda8360545505e208b